# Can i search a copy of a card in the battlefield in my library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If i use a [Cackling Counterpart](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cackling%20Counterpart) to create a token of a creature, can i use cards targeting that token (like [Pack Hunt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=21375)) to search my library for that same creature cards?

Answer (score 5):

When you create a copy of something you copy pretty much everything about it including its name <sup>[[706.2.]](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Copying_objects)</sup>. And Pack Hunt only needs a creature to target, it doesn't care if the creature is a token or a real card all it care about is that it is a creature. So Pack Hunt will happily find more of whatever creature you happened to copy.

If the created token isn't a copy, the effect that created the token gave it a name. This name is either specified explicitly by the instruction that created the token, or it defaults to the creature's type(s). This name will usually not be the name of the cards in your library, so you will generally not be able to find any matching cards. There are a few cards like [Llanowar Mentor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Llanowar%20Mentor) that makes tokens named [Llanowar Elves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Llanowar%20Elves) so if you had a token made by the Mentor you could find cards named Llanowar Elves. There is also an odd case with [Splintering Wind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Splintering%20Wind) which makes tokens named Splinter, which would allow you to find the card [Splinter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74615) even though it isn't a creature card.

Comment: _"This name will not be the name of the cards in your library, so you will not be able to find any matching cards. "_ I agree that this is _usually_ the case, but I can think of a few exceptions. For example, LLanowar Mentor creates tokens named "Llanowar Elves", so Pack Hunt ought to be able to search up the real version in that case. As for not-explicitly-named tokens, I don't know of any that share a name with a creature card. Can anything make a Viashino Skeleton token?

Comment: @Kevin - You can use Riptide Replicator or Volrath's Laboratory to make tokens of any creature type. There are several you can choose that also have matching card names, such as Atog, Brushwagg, Cockatrice, Juggernaut, Leviathan, Lhurgoyf, Masticore, etc.

Comment: @HaoYe Oh yeah, good thinking :-)